# Ubuntu 12.10 always hanging

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

I am new in Ubuntu 12.10. In installation process, I choose "ext4 extended..." when then appears "something else" and another option. Is that wrong? After installation, my computer is going to very much slow and always appear to hang.

My processor is Intel Dual-Core 2.5, Twin 1GB Ram, 250 GB Hard Disk, default video card and I have Windows XP in C drive and Ubuntu in D drive.

Comment: Slow in Windows or in Ubuntu? Are there any strange messages in `dmesg`?

Comment: No, But always appear to send report or quit application. My problem is only Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you dump the closing `strace` output of a program doing this, please?

Comment: sometime but not all times. sometime I have to restart